# "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: FILES is not defined" (newtab-serviceworker.js)

Tags: service-worker

I have a page with HTML form and some basic jQuery/AJAX. No warnings, no errors, everything works fine. However, when I leave my tab opened, I am getting plenty of these errors as time passes by:

```
VM15 newtab-serviceworker.js:16
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: FILES is not defined
```

This is the beginning of newtab-serviceworker.js (including line 16 (14 in the preview below)):

```
var EXTRA_FILES = ["/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.ntp.en.BHgEJkq1PQM.O/m=sx,jsa,ntp,d,csi/am=AEAMAI5MJQ/rt=j/d=1/rs=ACT90oGgBiwQpyhfkvk6s0qgYagIFi8yXQ",];
var CHECKSUM = "o9h2ps";

var BLACKLIST = [
  '/gen_204\?',
  '/async/',
  '/complete/',
];

var CACHENAME = 'newtab-static-' + CHECKSUM;

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(caches.open(CACHENAME).then(function(cache) {
    return cache.addAll(FILES);
  }));
});
```

Is that even code-related problem? Sounds like browser side stuff to me. I wasn't able to find some relevant information about this.

Comment: You define variable EXTRA_FILES but you use FILES.
Replace FILES by EXTRA_FILES and refresh page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to Google's reCAPTCHA. I started receiving the same error in Chrome once i added Google's reCAPTCHA v3 to my page.

The only thing I noticed is that the reCAPTCHA expired-callback is not calling my function, so this might be related.

Otherwise you can safely ignore this error.

Comment: That was it. The reCAPTCHA v2 produces this error on my site. Although no specific solution was provided, I still mark this as a correct answer as it is the best one yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a variable `EXTRA_FILES`:

```
var EXTRA_FILES = ["/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.ntp.en.BHgEJkq1PQM.O/m=sx,jsa,ntp,d,csi/am=AEAMAI5MJQ/rt=j/d=1/rs=ACT90oGgBiwQpyhfkvk6s0qgYagIFi8yXQ",];
```

In your caching code you do use `FILES` variable:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(caches.open(CACHENAME).then(function(cache) {
    return cache.addAll(FILES);
  }));
});
```

Think you will just need to correct this..

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but I have never worked with neither of these variables. I also haven't implemented any caching. I'm confused...

Comment: i added your code example's to my answer. so it should be clearer which locations i mean.

Comment: I get it, but that is not a code I wrote. It is from the newtab-serviceworker.js, I have never heard of that file before. It looks like some browser related file, that's why I am confused.

Comment: ahh.. so maybe this code is somehow injected in your build. some plugin oder node package could have done this. you even don't want to have a service worker?

Comment: To be honest I have a very little knowledge about service workers, but as far as I know I don't need them in my app. I'll try to find out if some plugin is causing this - the page I'm referring to is a part of a WordPress site, so this might be it. Although very few plugins are installed there yet - all of them popular and verified.

Comment: is this a public site you are maintaining? can you search by a term through all your codefiles?

Comment: I have the same problem)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a Chrome service worker that runs when you open a new tab, a quick search led me to the source code [here](https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab-serviceworker.js).

I'm running into the same issue after opening a new tab, running Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 on MacOS.

Seems to be safe to ignore and shouldn't impact your code, but I've reported to Chrome Devs anyway. Hopefully it's just a mislaid variable and they can fix it easy enough.